# Does AWS support a global IAM policy? Easiest way to attach policy to all roles?

Tags: amazon-iam

I have an iam policy that denies ec2 runinstance if it doesn't also include 4 required tags.

Our model is user > group > STS Assume Roles.  All EC2 provisioning is done by a number of roles.

Do I have to manually attach this policy to each role, or does AWS support a global policy feature?  What's the easiest way to deploy this iam policy to be global across all our accounts?

Answer (score 4):

Use [AWS Organisations](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/).

'My Organization' is an option on the account drop down within the console. From there it is straightforward to add a global policy. Add your JSON template to deny access to the EC2:RunInstances permission with conditions on the ec2:ResourceTag.

The Deny policy will take precedence over any allow policies you specify in the account roles.

Comment: Excellent!  AWS Organizations.  I hope this can help someone else. Unfortunately, our fortune 500 company's AWS ecosystem is so large it's an uphill political battle to get access to AWS Organizations feature. It's already been claimed and nobody in my immediate cube farm has access. I have around 20 accounts to manage.  Any similar global option scoped down to account level? appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Use scripts to automate the roles to each account. Cloudformation templates is one way. Also look into AWS Config with custom rules to check for instances that do not comply with your policy as changes are made and trigger alerts (Or terminate the resources..)